# HashSet in EF many to many

Tags: c#, entity-framework, many-to-many

I'm trying to implement many to many in EF Code-first. I have found this code :

```
 public class Student
    {
        public Student() { }

        public int StudentId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string StudentName { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }
    }

    public class Course
    {
        public Course()
        {
            this.Students = new HashSet<Student>();
        }

        public int CourseId { get; set; }
        public string CourseName { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
    }
```

I understand everything except :

```
    public Course()
    {
        this.Students = new HashSet<Student>();
    }
```

Can you tell me why this part is necessary? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's necessary because you have to instantiate the particular implementation of `ICollection` that you would like to use. `HashSet` implements a hash table that is very efficient for a lot of operations, for instance searching a large set for a single item. But you might have reasons for choosing some other implementation, like `List`. It is equally fine to instantiate the collection as `this.Students = new List<Student>();` - Entity Framework doesn't care, but the default is `HashSet` for efficiency reasons.