# Why do I need HashSet in many-to-many relation?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, many-to-many

I have found many tutorials that use HashSet ex

```
this.Supplier = new HashSet<supplier>();
```

In many-to-many relation. But som tutorials use the code below without HashSet (no more or less)

```
public partial class Product
{
    public Product()
    {
        this.Supplier = new HashSet<supplier>();
    }

    public long ProductID { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }

    //navigation property to Supplier
    public virtual ICollection<supplier> Supplier { get; set; }
}

public partial class Supplier
{
    public Supplier()
    {
        this.Product = new HashSet<product>();
    }

    public long SupplierID { get; set; }
    public string SupplierName { get; set; }

    // navigation property to Product
    public virtual ICollection<product> Product { get; set; }
}
```

When I tested the code above and deleted

```
    public xxxx()
    {
        this.xxxx = new HashSet<xxxx>();
    }
```

I still got an association table and a many-to-many relation.

Why do I need HashSet?

Comment: Its your navigation property (`ICollection<product>`) that defines the relationship. The code in the constructor just initializes it so its not `null`

Answer (score 3):

Usually many-to-many relationship defined with `ICollection` in both table models:

```
public virtual ICollection<supplier> Supplier { get; set; }

public virtual ICollection<product> Product { get; set; }
```

The presence of `ICollection` on models means that lazy loading is enabled, allowing EF to create derived classes for them.

About the use of `HashSet` inside model generations, ChrisV said in [HashSet in EF many to many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28691089/hashset-in-ef-many-to-many):

> HashSet implements a hash table that is very efficient for a lot of
>   operations, for instance searching a large set for a single item.

The usage of `HashSet` by default primarily based on efficiency reasons besides of non-null value, such like Yuval Itzchakov said in [Entity Framework:Why the collection type of entity class need to be instanced in the default constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29873671/entity-frameworkwhy-the-collection-type-of-entity-class-need-to-be-instanced-in):

> A HashSet is used because it guarantees that two values which are
>   equal to each other (which are equality checked by looking at their
>   GetHashCode and Equals methods) only appear once in the collection.
>   And yes, you can change the concrete type to any type which implements
>   `ICollection<T>`.

The explanations above can be summarized as "`HashSet` is initialization step of `ICollection` interface inside model's constructor which guarantees equality between each related model members". EF itself doesn't care what implementations should be apply on `ICollection` for table models, you can use `List<T>` in constructor replacing `HashSet<T>` and many-to-many relationship still doesn't affected.

Inside your template model (.tt file), you may see these lines to generate `HashSet<T>` by default as it implements `ICollection`:

```
foreach (var navigationProperty in collectionNavigationProperties)
{
#>
   this.<#=code.Escape(navigationProperty)#> = new HashSet<<#=typeMapper.GetTypeName(navigationProperty.ToEndMember.GetEntityType())#>>();
<#
}
```

You may doing experiments by removing or changing `HashSet<T>` initialization when the model is re-generated, however I considered not a good practice to remove it for large amount of data operations.